# Undefined Reference only for Box2D when compiling with Terminal GCC & G++

Tags: c++, gcc, terminal, g++, box2d

I'm having trouble compiling a program but only because of the Box2D static library (For Windows). Every other libary that I'm linking works just fine and the compiler does find the .lib. At first I tought it might be that I was compiling on x86 instead of x64 but I already tried both and got for x86 the incompatible library and for x64 the error message that I've been getting:

```
C:\Users\Aether\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEPbRRr.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZSt11make_uniqueI7b2WorldJ6b2Vec2EENSt9_MakeUniqIT_E15__single_objectEDpOT0_[_ZSt11make_uniqueI7b2WorldJ6b2Vec2EENSt9_MakeUniqIT_E15__single_objectEDpOT0_]+0x35): undefined reference to `b2World::b2World(b2Vec2 const&)'
C:\Users\Aether\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEPbRRr.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZNKSt14default_deleteI7b2WorldEclEPS0_[_ZNKSt14default_deleteI7b2WorldEclEPS0_]+0x23): undefined reference to `b2World::~b2World()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The command that I'm using to compile is:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -m64 -Iusr/inc -Iusr/includes -Iusr/src -o bin/Release/Starless.exe -Lusr/lib main.cpp -lfmodL64_vc -lopengl32 -lglew32s -lglfw3 -lSOIL -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lodbc32 -lodbccp32 -lfreetype -lfmod64_vc -lBox2D
```

I also already tried moving the -lBox2D to before specifing the file and after, it's practically been everywere in the command at this point, but still, doesn't work.

**Edit:**

Got it working BUT with msbuild (which means it is still not solved), which gives me a hint of the error. I didn't mention prior that I'm compiling two projects both with their own respective properties but one is a .dll and the other is the .exe which depends on the .dll. The only lib that they both need to share is Box2D.lib. I'm guessing that the problem goes there, they share a static library and when Compiling it's only giving once the location of the library. That's all I know for now, it works, kinda with msbuild, but I would still rather use the gnu compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the paths you are specifying for include files (with `-I`) and for libraries (with `-L`) are *relative* paths, not *absolute*. So you're telling it to look under the *current* directory. Surprised it got past compiling to linking, though the includes you've added are probably being ignored and found via built-in rules. You should specify the toolchain and platform - I assume this is Windows with MinGW or the like?

I question if these paths are having an effect:

```
    -Iusr/inc -Iusr/includes -Iusr/src
```

since they are relative paths, and also as `/usr/include` (without the 's') is the canonical path which should be built-in. The others don't appear to be canonical, but perhaps you have installed some source there?

Anyway the main problem is finding the library so you probably want your library path to be `/usr/lib` (assuming Box2D is installed there):

```
g++ -std=c++14 -m64 \
    -I/usr/inc -I/usr/includes -I/usr/src \
    -o bin/Release/Starless.exe \
    -L/usr/lib \
    -lfmodL64_vc -lopengl32 -lglew32s -lglfw3 -lSOIL \
    -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 \
    -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lodbc32 \
    -lodbccp32 -lfreetype -lfmod64_vc -lBox2D \
    main.cpp
```

Comment: Isn't it the same? I already tried it and got the same error, notice that the compiler doesn't say anything about not finding Box2D, it seems to find the library but still gives undefined reference.

Comment: No, the paths have a leading slash. The FAQ https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-my-code-compile-andor-link mentions common problems with linking are mixing versions of headers and libraries. How have you installed Box2D and are you certain there is only one version found? If any signatures have changed, that could explain this error.

Comment: Visual Studio compiles normally with the same .lib to problem just appears when using g++

Comment: I just noticed something really interesting, Visual Studio Compiles normally but when using the msbuild command on the same .sln file gives the same error as g++